# JDBC ResultSet getDate losing precision

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc, resultset

I am losing precision in my ResultSet.getDate(x) calls.  Basically:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.getDate("MODIFIED");
```

is returning dates truncated to the day where MODIFIED is an Oracle TIMESTAMP field of default precision.  I think there may be some JDBC tweak I'm missing; usually TIMESTAMP is compatible with DATE, but I'm hoping I don't have to redefine the entire table.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[`ResultSet.getDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(int)) returns a `java.sql.Date`, not a `java.util.Date`. It is defined to be a timeless date.
If you want a timestamp, use [`ResultSet.getTimestamp()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp(int))!

Comment: Note to self - rtfm.  I thought this was working in other places.

Comment: "java.sql.Date is defined to be a timeless date". That statement has saved my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should use java.sql.Timestamp instead of java.sql.Date. You can use it as a java.util.Date object afterward if necessary.

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp("MODIFIED");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Constructing `new Date` is unnecessary since `Timestamp extends Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Timestap is the correct way. 
Please take not that with Timestamp you will not be able to set the columns to nullable if you were to use Liquibase.

A problem I came across as well.