# SimpleDateFormat returning wrong time value ( 00:00:00)

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm having an issue using the SimpleDateFormat component.

I have a date stored in my database as a DateTime, and i would like to get the value of this datetime in my application.

I'm using a SimpleDateFormat in order to do this, but the problem is that it always returns me 00:00:00 as Time. The date is well returned though.

So i'm doing as follows :

```
private final static SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM - HH:mm:ss");

public Push(int idp, String titrefr, String contenufr, String titreuk, String contenuuk, String pays, String marche, String type, Date datep, int isImportant, String  image) {

    super();

    this.idp = idp;
    this.titrefr = titrefr;
    this.contenufr= contenufr;
    this.titreuk = titreuk;
    this.contenuuk= contenuuk;
    this.pays = pays;
    this.marche = marche;
    this.type = type;
    this.datep = ft.format(datep);
    this.isImportant = isImportant;
    this.image = image;
    System.out.println(this.datep);
}
```

Here is the method where I get the date :

`Modele.java:`

```
public List<Push> getPushfr() {
    String queryPushfr = "SELECT idp,titrefr,contenufr,titreuk,contenuuk,pays,marche,type,datep,isImportant, image FROM push WHERE datep > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) ORDER BY datep DESC;";
    try {
        connexion = ConnexionBDD.getConnexion();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = connexion.prepareStatement(queryPushfr);
        resultat = pstmt.executeQuery(queryPushfr);
        while (resultat.next()) {
            int idp = resultat.getInt("idp");
            String titrefr = resultat.getString("titrefr");
            String contenufr = resultat.getString("contenufr");
            String titreuk = resultat.getString("titreuk");
            String contenuuk = resultat.getString("contenuuk");
            String pays = resultat.getString("pays");
            String marche = resultat.getString("marche");
            String type = resultat.getString("type");
            Date datep = resultat.getDate("datep");
            int isImportant = resultat.getInt("isImportant");
            String image = resultat.getString("image");
            this.pushfr.add(
                    new Push(idp, titrefr, contenufr, titreuk, contenuuk, pays, marche, type, datep, isImportant,image));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return pushfr;
}
```

In my database the date is :

```
2015-09-03 16:13:09
```

The output i get from my `System.out.println(datep)` is

```
03.09 - 00:00:00
```

I've no idea why it's not returning me the time properly..

Comment: Looks fine. Can you should how you are `SELECT`ing the date from the database?

Comment: @SeanBright Yeah sure, i added it in the post :)

Comment: @DeveloppeurDuTurfu - See the linked duplicate for the answer. You should also delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using java.sql.Date you will lose information about the time.

> java.sql.Date corresponds to SQL DATE which means it stores years,
>   months and days while hour, minute, second and millisecond are
>   ignored.

Change code to:

```
public List<Push> getPushfr() {
    String queryPushfr = "SELECT idp,titrefr,contenufr,titreuk,contenuuk,pays,marche,type,datep,isImportant, image FROM push WHERE datep > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH) ORDER BY datep DESC;";
    try {
        connexion = ConnexionBDD.getConnexion();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = connexion.prepareStatement(queryPushfr);
        resultat = pstmt.executeQuery(queryPushfr);
        while (resultat.next()) {
            int idp = resultat.getInt("idp");
            String titrefr = resultat.getString("titrefr");
            String contenufr = resultat.getString("contenufr");
            String titreuk = resultat.getString("titreuk");
            String contenuuk = resultat.getString("contenuuk");
            String pays = resultat.getString("pays");
            String marche = resultat.getString("marche");
            String type = resultat.getString("type");
            Date datep = resultat.getTimestamp("datep");
            int isImportant = resultat.getInt("isImportant");
            String image = resultat.getString("image");
            this.pushfr.add(
                    new Push(idp, titrefr, contenufr, titreuk, contenuuk, pays, marche, type, datep, isImportant,image));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return pushfr;
}
```

PD:I recomend you to store the TimeStamt in milisecons in the database.

Comment: Thanks bro it's working perfectly like that !

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading results from a [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), use [getTimestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp-int-) method, not getDate. See [JDBC ResultSet getDate losing precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266530/jdbc-resultset-getdate-losing-precision)